# wrong React component design?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Maybe it's silly to ask this, but I'm stuck and I can't go on.

Since i have added removePerson and the button funcionality, I always get a error in the Persons component

```
const Persons = ({persons, searchName, removePerson}) => {
  //console.log(searchName)
  const exp = new RegExp( searchName, 'i' );
  const result =  persons.filter(person => person.name.match(exp))
  console.log(result + "inside Persons")
  return (
    result.map(person => <p key = {person.name}>{person.name}: {person.number} 
      <button onClick={() => removePerson(person.id)}>Delete</button></p>)
  )
}
```

When I delete a user from db.json I get the following error:

```
persons.filter is not a function
TypeError: persons.filter is not a function
```

If I remove the `<button onClick={() => removePerson(person.id)}>Delete</button>` functionality from Persons, the app works as expected.

```
// EDITED (GOOD!!)
const removePerson = (id) => {
    axios.get(`http://localhost:3001/persons/${id}`).then((response) => {
      const confirm = window.confirm(`Delete ${response.data.name} ?`);
      console.log(response.data.name);

      if (confirm) {
        axios
          .delete(`http://localhost:3001/persons/${id}`)
          .then((response) => personService.getAll())
          .then((response) => setPersons(response.data));
      }
    });
  };
```

Before adding removePerson it displayed the names perfectly.

```
const App = () => {

 const [ persons, setPersons] = useState([])
 const [ searchName, setSearchName] = useState('')
 ...
 return (
  ...
  <Persons persons={persons} searchName={searchName} removePerson= 
   {removePerson}/>
  ...
}
```

```
//services/persons.js
import axios from 'axios'
const baseUrl = 'http://localhost:3001/persons'

const getAll = () => {
  return axios.get(baseUrl)
}
...
```

Now I manage to delete the desired name from bd.json, but the app explodes.

```
//db.json
{
  "persons": [
    {
      "name": "Isaac Asimov",
      "number": "933445566",
      "id": 5
    },
    {
      "name": "Frederick Forsyth",
      "number": "400556688",
      "id": 6
    },
    {
      "name": "Fiodor Dostoyievski",
      "number": "999125645",
      "id": 7
    },
    ...
  ]
}
```

I'm fairly new to React and I think the problem is in the design of this component (Persons), and that I can't combine these two functionalities in it, search and delete elements, but I don't know how to solve it without turning almost everything around.

Any help would be appreciated.

---EDITED--

```
...
if (query) {
        axios
          .delete(`http://localhost:3001/persons/${id}`)
          .then((response) => {
            console.log(response.data + "  after delete");
            return personService.getAll();
          })
          .then((response) => setPersons(response.persons));
      }
```

It continues to delete the item but then throws the same error:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'filter')
    at Persons (App.js:15:1)
    at renderWithHooks (react-dom.development.js:16305:1)
    at updateFunctionComponent (react-dom.development.js:19588:1)
....
```

```
const Persons = ({persons, searchName, removePerson}) => {
  //console.log(searchName)
  const exp = new RegExp( searchName, 'i' );
  15:1 --->>> const result =  persons.filter(person => person.name.match(exp))**
  console.log(result + "inside Persons")
  return (
    result.map(person => <p key = {person.name}>{person.name}: {person.number} 
      <button onClick={() => removePerson(person.id)}>Delete</button></p>)
  )
}
```

I still don't understand why this component works correctly when I remove the functionality to delete items from db.json and only show them. No error about filter.

```
const Persons = ({persons, searchName}) => {
  //console.log(searchName)
  const exp = new RegExp( searchName, 'i' );
  const result =  persons.filter(person => person.name.match(exp))
  console.log(result + "inside Persons")
  return (
    result.map(person => <p key = {person.name}>{person.name}: {person.number} </p>)
  )
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> persons.filter is not a function

If `persons.filter` is not a function then `persons` is not an array.  So what is it?  If this operation:

```
personService.getAll()
```

results in the JSON you're showing near the end of the question then that is indeed not an array.  It's an object.  You can set the state to the property on that object which has an array.  For example:

```
.then((response) => setPersons(response.persons))
```

Basically, it's important to observe and understand your own data structures.  Objects and arrays are different things.  (Technically an array *is* an object, but it's one which has a specific structure.)

---

As an aside... This looks like a hack:

```
if (query) {
  axios
    .delete(`http://localhost:3001/persons/${id}`)
    .then((response) => console.log(response.data));
}
setTimeout(() => {
  personService.getAll().then((response) => setPersons(response.persons));
}, 1000);
```

What exactly is the purpose of `setTimeout` here?  Why always wait exactly one second?  If the goal is to fetch the updated data after the delete operation, then do it after the delete operation:

```
if (query) {
  axios
    .delete(`http://localhost:3001/persons/${id}`)
    .then((response) => personService.getAll())
    .then((response) => setPersons(response.persons));
}
```

Or, if you still want to log the delete response to the console:

```
if (query) {
  axios
    .delete(`http://localhost:3001/persons/${id}`)
    .then((response) => {
      console.log(response.data);
      return personService.getAll();
    )
    .then((response) => setPersons(response.persons));
}
```

Don't use artificial timers as a workaround to asynchronous code.

Comment: I appreciate your answers and clarifications.

Comment: @Kalasni: Regarding the updated question... Maybe it should be `setPersons(response.data.persons)` instead?  Any way you look at it, *your* next step is to do some debugging.  Observe what `response` actually is at runtime and what actual data you want to set to the state value.  Simply guessing isn't working for you.

Comment: Finally it was simply to setPersons to the data contained in response  **setPersons(response.data)** `axios
          .delete(`http://localhost:3001/persons/${id}`)
          .then((response) => personService.getAll())
          .then((response) => setPersons(response.data));`  Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

It seems like you are setting the `persons` state as the object from the response, instead of the array inside of it:

```js
// in service/persons.js
const getAll = () => {
  return axios.get(baseUrl)
}

// inside the removePerson function
setTimeout(() => {      
  personService.getAll().then((response) => 
  setPersons(response));
}, 1000);
```

which means the `persons` state would currently contain the following object: `{ persons: [/*...*/] }` which means there isn't a `.filter` function inside of it, that's why you're receiving such error.

I guess you wanted to access the `persons` array inside of it, such as:

```js
setTimeout(() => {      
  personService.getAll().then((response) => 
  setPersons(response.persons));
}, 1000);
```

Comment: I appreciate your answers and clarifications, @douglas